# How to handle sql with Custom List Table Example

Tags: wp-list-table

I am using the Custom List Table Example plugin as a base to display entries from a table I created in the wordpress database...

However I am having issues with this function

```
function column_default($item, $column_name){

}
```

I get the error message:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
```

In the example in the plugin, it uses a simple array. But the $data returned from the query returns several rows of data (i.e. an array with object, object, object).

Inside of my prepare_items() function:

```
 global $wpdb;
          $orderby = (!empty($_REQUEST['orderby'])) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'name'; //If no sort, default to title
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_nc_location ORDER BY " . $orderby;
          $data = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the IF statement. Try just using `$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_nc_location ORDER BY title`.

Comment: Nope. Still the same error

Comment: Please post the whole function and add `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($data); echo '</pre>';` add the end to it and post the result.

Comment: You may wish to take a look at the [example plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-list-table-example/) to get a better grasp of how to use the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by passing $item as an array

```
function column_default($item, $column_name){
$item = (array)($item)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

Adding `ARRAY_A` forces `get_results` to return an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to retrieve data from custom tables:

```
  // Retrieve all seasons registered
  function get_registered_seasons() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name   = $wpdb->prefix . "cwgallery";    
    $sql          = "SELECT DISTINCT year, season FROM $table_name ORDER BY year DESC ";
    $result  = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    return $result;
  }
```

Comment: When I print_f on my $data it's showing my data (in array form)...so that part is working. My problem is that I am not very familiar with the built-in Wordpress Class to List a table in the admin section...